# Facebook API: post comment from another site. Is it possible?

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, oauth

I have registered a new app on facebook using the new Heroku App. 
 'https://high-meadow-3906.herokuapp.com/'

What i want to do is to comment on facebook while browsing another website (9gag.com)

I am planning to use Chrome Extension that will inject javascript into this 9gag.com site.
When a user key-presses 'c', i want to post a comment on facebook comments social plugin.

Should i make this post call from the chrome extension or my facebook app domain or the injected code into 9gag.com?

How to grab the access token and pass it to the above post call?